# One NetBeans Project can load a .dll but another throws "Can't load AMD 64-bit .dll on a IA 32-bit platform"

Tags: java, netbeans

I have two NetBeans projects - project A, a standard Java app that exists only to prove a concept, and project B which is a legacy app that I copied my code into.  Project B is a NetBeans IDE Framework app.   Project A executes the following code successfully but Project B throws the error:

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load AMD 64-bit .dll on a IA 32-bit platform

I have only one version of NetBeans and only one version of the Java JDK ("1.8.0_121" 64 bit).

```
        Path dllFilePath = Paths.get ("c:\\jnetpcap.dll");
        if (Files.exists(dllFilePath)) {
            System.out.println(dllFilePath+" exists!!!");
        } else {
            System.out.println(dllFilePath+" doesn't exist???");            
        }
        System.load(dllFilePath.toString())
```

As an additional puzzle, Project B can't find the dll if it's in \System32\ but Project A can.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like project B is using a 32 bit JVM. Any chance the project somehow embeds a JVM of its own? What does `System.getProperty("java.home")` return?

Comment: The two projects do indeed point to different homes (B points to the x86 path).  Both use the same netbeans.conf file so project B must be changing it somehow.  Just gotta find how.   Thanks for the suggestion!!

Comment: SOLUTION:  There was, in fact, another version of Netbeans (11) that I had not completely removed.   When I ran uninstall.exe, Project B behaved like Project A.  I'm not sure why only one of the projects had a problem with the other version.